# div when hovered gets dragged along with when page is scrolled

Tags: html, css

I am stuck at an issue and need some one to help me.
Have created a sample fiddle to explain the functionality.

When I hover over `li` tag the respective `div` is hovered. I wanted all `div`s of corresponding `li` tag to be shown at same position so have used `position` as `fixed`.

However, the issue is when the cursor is placed on hovered `div` and page is scrolled the hovered `div`s get dragged along with when scrolled which should not happen. Can someone please help me resolve this issue?

Here is the screenshot of the issue

[image]

```css
.lidiv {
  display: none;
}

.ulclass li:hover .lidiv {
  display: block
}

.ulclass {
  list-style: none
}

.lidiv {
  position: fixed;
  left: 20%;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="divoneclass">
  <ul class="ulclass">
    <li class="liclass">
      <a class="aclass" href="javascript:void(0)">
        <span class="spanclassupp">
          <span class="spantitle">DOG</span>
        </span>
      </a>
      <div class="lidiv">
        <div class="lidivone">
          <div class="lidivtwo">
            <div class="lidivthree">
              <div class="lidivfour">
                <div class="diccontent">
                  <p>
                    LI ONE VALUE
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="liclass">
      <a class="aclass" href="javascript:void(0)">
        <span class="spanclassupp">
          <span class="spantitle">CAT</span>
        </span>
      </a>
      <div class="lidiv">
        <div class="lidivone">
          <div class="lidivtwo">
            <div class="lidivthree">
              <div class="lidivfour">
                <div class="diccontent">
                  <p>
                    LI TWO VALUE
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="liclass">
      <a class="aclass" href="javascript:void(0)">
        <span class="spanclassupp">
          <span class="spantitle">OTHER</span>
        </span>
      </a>
      <div class="lidiv">
        <div class="lidivone">
          <div class="lidivtwo">
            <div class="lidivthree">
              <div class="lidivfour">
                <div class="diccontent">
                  <p>
                    LI THREE VALUE
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: your fiddle link is not working!!

Comment: Position fixed positions the element according to the viewport. Are you looking for position absolute?

Comment: using absolute position shows respective div of li in front of respective li.For example for first li its div was shown in front of that..similarly for second.What I want is when I hover over any li its respective div should at only one position.